# yelp error :INVALID_SIGNATURE

Tags: php, oauth, yelp

I get this error when I try to run my yelp api:

```
{"error":{"text":"Signature was
invalid","id":"INVALID_SIGNATURE","description":"Expired timestamp:
given 1303539322 and now 1303541647 has a greater difference than
threshold 300"}}
```

What can I do to overcome this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a valid signature. ... kidding aside, you have to give us more information, what do you do? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: ... but to be honest, its written clearly in the error what's gone wrong. the given timestamp is to old and the difference is creater 300. make sure your server runs on the proper/right time (ntpdate)

Comment: I use the yelp api and load the lib:oauth.The time stamp i pass to YELP API has to be within 300ms of their machine time.

Comment: The 'oauth_signature' which you have passed as a parameter for authentication might be wrong. Check it again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your computer(dev machine or server) Timezone to the correct one.

As @Rufinus said, your server has to run on the proper/right time (that's the correct answer), I found this a few minutes ago, I toke borrow a machine and tried to run my YELP app and start throwing the same error, I change the TimeZone Setting of the laptop, and now is running again.

in windows: 
    left click over the clock > click "change date and time settings..." > click "change time zone"

select from the Select options the proper one.

Answer (score 0):

In the OAuth.php file I changed:

```
private static function generate_timestamp() {
  return time();
}
```

to

```
private static function generate_timestamp() {
  return time() + 10000;
}
```